# Adding a URI icon using Blade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, icons, uri, laravel-blade

I am trying to add a facebook icon and link to the footer of my page using [icon-finder](http://www.iconfinder.com/icons/386622/face_book_facebook_icon#size=64). I am using blade in Laravel 4.2.

I have tried the following without success.

```
    <div class="col-sm-4" align="center"> 
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/elizabeth.widman.1" target="blank">
        <p align="center">
            <img src="{{ asset('https://www.facebook.com/elizabeth.widman.1" 
            src="data:image/png;base64,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 style='); }}"  
            alt="Generic placeholder image" 
            style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" 
            class="img-responsive">
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Any advice is greatly apprechiated

Comment: you've got quite a few syntax errors...

Answer (score 1):

You've got syntax errors all over that img tag. here try this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"  
     alt="Generic placeholder image" 
     style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" 
     class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: Thank you. As you can tell I am new to web development.